# Delete attribute from class instance python

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes

I have example class:

```
class A():
    other_attribute = 2
    def __init__(self):
        setattr(A,"my_attribute",1)

a = A()
```

How can I delete `my_attribute` and `other_attribute` from instance?

PS. I edited code to better explain problem. For example I have class, which dynamically adds attributes

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, attribute_name, attribute_value):
        setattr(A, attribute_name, attribute_value)

a = A("my_attribute", 123)
```

I created `my_attribute`, in instance `a`, but then I do not need it anymore. But at other instances are other attributes, which I do not want to change.

Comment: `other_attribute` is not on the instance.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: neither is `my_attribute`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oops! I didn't see they are using `A` inside `setattr.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`other_attribute` and `my_attribute` are not an attributes on the instance. They are attributes on the *class*. You'd have to delete attributes from there, or provide an instance attribute with the same name (and a different value) to mask the class attribute.

Deleting the attributes from the class means that they'll not be available anymore on *any* instance.

You cannot 'delete' class attributes on individual instances. If an attribute is not to be shared by all instances, don't make them class attributes.

Comment: Actually, I need dynamically add and delete attributes in instances. For example, I'll have class `measurements`. In initialization I'll add attributes, like "voltages", "time", "temperature", which will be lists of values. But what if I want to delete some of them? For example some instance have "voltage" and "temperature". I do not need "voltage" anymore. But other instances have anoter attributes.

Comment: @artsin: then make them attributes on `self` and not on the class.

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: Thank you,  Martijn!

Answer (score 5):

other_attribute is shared by all instances of A, that means it is a part of

```
  A.__dict__
```

dictionary. You can do this for one instance of a class if you initialize an attribute in the constructor:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.attrib = 2
    self.attrib2 = 3

a = A()
print "Before " + str(a.__dict__)
del a.__dict__["attrib"];
print "After " + str(a.__dict__)
```

Output is:

```
Before {'attrib2': 3, 'attrib': 2}
After {'attrib2': 3}
```